# Trying to solve the card shuffle and birthday paradox question

Tags: probability, birthday

I'm trying to solve the question as to whether two 52 card shuffles have ever been the same but I can't calculate the final step. Additionally I can't find any answer on the internet that has approached the question in the same way. If anyone can help explain what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Assumptions:**

1. Every card shuffle is independent with probability **1/52!**
2. There have been $n$ card shuffles in all of history

**My solution thus far:**

Consider the first person to ever shuffle a deck of cards. Let's call the resulting shuffle **X1**. What is the probability that **X1** is never repeated? This is $(1-1/52!)^{n-1}$

Consider the second person to ever shuffle a deck of cards. Let's call the resulting shuffle **X2**. What is the probability that **X2** is never subsequently (aka given **X2** is not itself a repeat of **X1**) repeated? This is $(1-1/52!)^{n-2}$

If we carry this logic on, then the probability of $(n-1)^{th}$ shuffle (we'll call this **Xn**) being subsequently repeated will be $(1-1/52!)^{1}$

Therefore the probability that no shuffles has ever been repeated is

$(1-1/52!)^{n-1} \times (1-1/52!)^{n-2}... \times (1-1/52!)^{1}$ = $(1-1/52!)^{(n-1)!}$

**Calculations**
Now I think the next step would be set this equal to $1/2$ and solve for $n$.

Notice the following:

1. When $n = 1$, $(1-1/52!)^{(n-1)!} \approx 1$
2. As $0 < 1-1/52! < 1$, therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-1/52!)^{(n-1)!} = 0$

Therefore there must be values of $n$ that we'll call $(a,b)$  (where $a = b+1$) which will give the following result:

$(1-1/52!)^{(a-1)!} > 0.5$

$(1-1/52!)^{(b-1)!} < 0.5$

**So my query is:**

How do I calculate $(a,b)$? The software I've tried (Excel and R) just simplify $1-1/52! = 1$ so I haven't been able to proceed with the calculation.

Are my workings sound? I can't find anyone else who has $(n-1)!$ as their power. Have I made a logical error?

Thank you.

Comment: Suppose there are $n$ persons in a room, and every body is shaking hands. How many handshakes are exchanged in total? This is the standard formulation for the problem.

Comment: $n$ persons in a room, and everybody shaking hands?  Yikes, they'll all spread coronavirus!

Comment: The probability that no shuffles has ever been repeated should be $(1-0/52!) \times (1-1/52!) \times (1-2/52!)... \times (1-(n-1)/52!) = \dfrac{(52!)!}{(52!-n)!\,(52!)^n}$ for $n \le 52!$ and $0$ for $n>52!$.  That assumes all shuffles are equally likely and independent.  In reality, cardsharps and magicians can control shuffles and the best can repeat shuffles exactly

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is fine, but the usual one is to say the first shuffle is guaranteed to be unique, the second is unique so far with probability $1-\frac 1{52!}$, the third is unique so far with probability $1-\frac 2{52!}$ and the $n^{th}$ is unique so far with probability $1-\frac {n-1}{52!}$.  Then you multiply these all together and compare with $\frac 12$.  That doesn't give the $(n-1)!$ in the exponent, which is why you haven't seen it.

The [Wikipedia page on the birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) shows that for large numbers $n$ of possibilities, and $52!$ is certainly large, the number of tries to get a $50\%$ chance of a match is $\sqrt {2 (\log 2) n}$.  Taking $n=52!$ we get about $1.05\cdot 10^{34}$.  That is huge compared to the number of person-seconds in history, so the chance of a duplicate is miniscule.